# How to Update JRXML from old jasper to new jasper.?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a *JRXML* report built in an old *iReport 3.0*, and now I want to Update it to newer *iReport 4.7*.

What are the steps to do so, please explain?

Comment: Have you tried just opening it in iReport 4.7?  I've noticed all of my old reports can be opened by newer iReport versions and it converts the XML cleanly.

Comment: If I have a huge number of reports then I have to open them all and compile manually. Is there some generic method to do it OR this is the only One..?

Comment: You can use the "Massive Processing Tool" under Tools.  It should process things nicely for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the script located in /buildomatic inside jasperserver folder.

The recommended procedure is described in the Installation Guide
Chapter 7. In this procedure, you run the js-upgrade script:

```
  js-upgrade-newdb-ce.bat/sh
```